# В питоне выдает ошибку 401 при подключении бота в телеграмме

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot

[image: запустил код выдало ошибку 401 то есть не может связаться с сервером (насколько я это понял)]

написал бота для телеграмма ввел токен запустил код и мне вывело ошибку. включил впн думал что поможет не помогло...
как говорят "на этом мои полномочия фсе"
если не трудно можете подсказать как исправить?

```
import telebot;
bot = telebot.TeleBot('тут токен который я не дам >=[');

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def get_text_messages(message):
  if message.text == "Привет":
      bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Привет, сейчас я расскажу тебе гороскоп на сегодня.")
  elif message.text == "/help":
      bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Напиши Привет")
  else:
      bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Я тебя не понимаю. Напиши /help.")
        
bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

ты токен не указал, его можно получить у @BotFather